# Where is documentation on Arduino's Internal Interrupts?

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, ide, atmel-studio

First time arduino programmer here...however I have programmed the TI MSP430 in the past...

I am trying to figure out how to configure internal Interrupt Vectors on this Arduino Uno.

In the Arduino IDE, I am skeptical about writing lines of code like

```
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect) {
    Serial.Print("Entered Capture Vector");
}
```

Because it doesn't appear to matter what I type inside ISR(), for instance I can write 
    ISR(GibERisH) {
    }

And it still compiles and uploads to the arduino. What?! Also how could Arduino IDE know what the heck TIMER1_CAPT_vect is without having the library?

I found a list of interrupt vector names here: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html

But I can not find documentation ANYWHERE ELSE on what to call these interrupt vectors.

Should I abandon the Arduino IDE and go with the Atmel Studio 6.2 (There is a juicy looking arduino plug-in...)? I need advanced control of the guts of this processor, and there is zero documentation about how to do this anywhere on the internet.

---

EDIT: I realized my problem was I was looking for documentation for the atmega16U2 (that does something else on the board), not the atmega328P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vector names are all defined within the header files for the main chip in the compiler.  The IDE doesn't need to know anything about that kind of thing - that's all up to the compiler.

Look for the files "lib/avr/include/avr/io*.h within the compiler in your chosen IDE.  In there are all the chips and all their definitions.

For instance, the ATMega328P definition (iom328p.h) has this list:

```
#define INT0_vect         _VECTOR(1)   /* External Interrupt Request 0 */
#define INT1_vect         _VECTOR(2)   /* External Interrupt Request 1 */
#define PCINT0_vect       _VECTOR(3)   /* Pin Change Interrupt Request 0 */
#define PCINT1_vect       _VECTOR(4)   /* Pin Change Interrupt Request 0 */
#define PCINT2_vect       _VECTOR(5)   /* Pin Change Interrupt Request 1 */
#define WDT_vect          _VECTOR(6)   /* Watchdog Time-out Interrupt */
#define TIMER2_COMPA_vect _VECTOR(7)   /* Timer/Counter2 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER2_COMPB_vect _VECTOR(8)   /* Timer/Counter2 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER2_OVF_vect   _VECTOR(9)   /* Timer/Counter2 Overflow */
#define TIMER1_CAPT_vect  _VECTOR(10)  /* Timer/Counter1 Capture Event */
#define TIMER1_COMPA_vect _VECTOR(11)  /* Timer/Counter1 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER1_COMPB_vect _VECTOR(12)  /* Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B */
#define TIMER1_OVF_vect   _VECTOR(13)  /* Timer/Counter1 Overflow */
#define TIMER0_COMPA_vect _VECTOR(14)  /* TimerCounter0 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER0_COMPB_vect _VECTOR(15)  /* TimerCounter0 Compare Match B */
#define TIMER0_OVF_vect   _VECTOR(16)  /* Timer/Couner0 Overflow */
#define SPI_STC_vect      _VECTOR(17)  /* SPI Serial Transfer Complete */
#define USART_RX_vect     _VECTOR(18)  /* USART Rx Complete */
#define USART_UDRE_vect   _VECTOR(19)  /* USART, Data Register Empty */
#define USART_TX_vect     _VECTOR(20)  /* USART Tx Complete */
#define ADC_vect          _VECTOR(21)  /* ADC Conversion Complete */
#define EE_READY_vect     _VECTOR(22)  /* EEPROM Ready */
#define ANALOG_COMP_vect  _VECTOR(23)  /* Analog Comparator */
#define TWI_vect          _VECTOR(24)  /* Two-wire Serial Interface */
#define SPM_READY_vect    _VECTOR(25)  /* Store Program Memory Read */
```

Further, _ISR() is just a macro.  It creates a suitable function prototype for your function, and if that happens to include a valid vector then it becomes an ISR.

```
#  define ISR(vector, ...)            \
    extern "C" void vector (void) __attribute__ ((signal,__INTR_ATTRS)) __VA_ARGS__; \
    void vector (void)
```

That is defined in "avr/interrupt.h" in the compiler's include files.  With your gibberish you'd end up with:

```
extern "C" void GibERisH (void) __attribute__ ((signal,__INTR_ATTRS));
void GibERisH (void) {
    // something here
}
```

With a real vector you'd get the more meaningful:

```
extern "C" void _VECTOR(7) (void) __attribute__ ((signal,__INTR_ATTRS));
void _VECTOR(7) (void) {
    // something here
}
```

Of course, _VECTOR() itself is a macro:

lib/avr/include/avr/sfr_defs.h:#define _VECTOR(N) __vector_ ## N

So that further expands out to:

```
extern "C" void __vector_7 (void) __attribute__ ((signal,__INTR_ATTRS));
void __vector_7 (void) {
    // something here
}
```

And magically, that new function name of `__vector_7` is directly referenced from the standard vector handling code in the startup library *crt* of the AVR compiler.

Comment: Thank Majenko. Also the documentation actually does have the names of the interrupts, but looking at the header makes it crystal clear. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

```
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect) {
    Serial.Print("Entered Capture Vector");
}
```

Rule #1. Don't do serial prints inside an ISR. Doing that will likely hang the sketch.

> Because it doesn't appear to matter what I type inside ISR(), for instance I can write ISR(GibERisH) { }

Yes you can do that. It just degrades into some function that is never called. The way it is organized with all the defines, any non-valid ISR name effectively creates a non-ISR function, which is therefore ignored. Even getting the capitalization wrong can cause this.

> I need advanced control of the guts of this processor, and there is zero documentation about how to do this anywhere on the internet.

There is a considerable amount of detail on my site: http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts